# Android how to name image to save in /camera?

Tags: java, android, file, camera

I built a camera app. My problem is that I want to continue the logical naming the default camera app uses.

EG: The camera app produces files such as:

```
IMG_20130104_033852
IMG_20130104_033853
```

If these are the only contents of my /camera folder, I should theoretically name my photo `IMG_20130104_033854`. Should I look for the image with the "biggest" name and add a number or is there a better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest building the name up until the point you get to the last sequence of numbers, and then you could look for the biggest number and add one to it if you feel like it. 

So for instance, based off of today's date, you could build the `IMG_20130121_` part. You could do `File [] fList = f.listFiles();`, where `f` is pointing to the `/camera/` directory. From there, you could check the files by doing `fileName.startsWith("IMG_20130121_")` in an IF statement. 
From there, do a substring to grab the string-numbers after the last underscore (_), convert to Integer, and loop through until you finish comparing all the Integers. 

 
I did this for folder names. A standalone cd burning device creates folders that start with `ezb_`, followed by a number. I can paste my looping code tomorrow if this info wasn't enough.

 
As a sidenote, if you were to start your own naming algorithm after `IMG_20130121_`, like adding an s or something, you'd still have to either keep track or look for the biggest number. You might as well just implement something like what I tried to explain. Let me know if I need to clarify!

Comment: I'll probably do that, but I was afraid it might conflict with the camera app. EG there was just a photo named IMG_1 and I added another called IMG_2 and then the camera APP tried to save on top of IMG_2 or something. Am I clear??

Comment: Yes. So the idea is to find the biggest number according to the date. after finding the biggest number that starts with IMG_20130121_, add one to it.

Comment: EDIT: OH I see what you mean about the regular camera app trying to save on top of IMG_2. I don't think that will be a problem, but just in case just add a letter or something to make it always unique. Like I said you could do `IMG_20130121_S1`, `..._S2`, etc.

Comment: yeah, but that would mess the order too. I'll test it and see what the camera app does